# FactoryGirl standard way of creating complex factories (model coupling concern)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

So I'm working with a complex code base, with lots of models of an ERP solution done in Rails 4 with RSpec and FactoryGirl. Fortunately it has lots of tests, not as much as would be ideal, but a reasonable number. One of the struggling points has been the complex factory setups. For example, to create a simple invoice we have to do a lot of work:

```
product = create(:product, business: test_business, price: 100)
activity = create(:activity, business: test_business)
create(:sales_point, business: test_business, fiscal_number: 1)
user = create(:user)
Invoice.create!(business: test_business,
                sales_point: 1,
                invoice_type: InvoiceType::INVOICE_B,
                receptor_fiscal_category: FiscalCategory::BUSINESS_A,
                details: [InvoiceDetail.new( product: product,
                                             description: product.name,
                                             unitary_amount: 100,
                                             quantity: 1,
                                             amount: 100,
                                             activity: activity)],
                total_net: 100,
                total_tax: 21,
                total_amount: 121,
                created_by: user,
                updated_by: user)
```

And that's only for creating a simple invoice for testing! I know that Thoughtbot, the FactoryGirl creators, actually advocate against having multiple factories for the same model or too much complexity in them. And I can understand why: when you start using too much magic in factories, they get too coupled to your tests and then when you change something **BANG!** hundreds of test start failing.

So instead of changing stuff, or trying to be 'too smart' we ended up with 5-10 versions of factories for complex models like `Invoice` (e.g. `invoice_by_total_amount`, `invoice_by_product_list`, `invoice_cash`, etc).

The question is, **if you have ever worked in big codebases like this** (100~ models), what where the recommended way to deal with this kind of complex setup to create objects for tests? How successful was it?

Comment: This all seems pretty normal. The standard factory_girl approach would be to write an Invoice factory which automatically creates its associated objects. Have you tried that? Did it work well for you? There is some specific fiddling needed to get factory_girl to use the same transitive dependency for multiple associations, but it's not clear to me if that's the problem you're having.

Comment: Yes we did that.. but did different test needed different tweaks on the invoice generated model and started to get very coupled to the factory. Also we ended with about 5-6 different versions of invoice factory.

Comment: Possibly you should show a couple of versions of the factory and ask how to consolidate them.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend wrapping that block of code in a function and pass what type of invoice you want as a parameter.

These type of functions can be put in a helper file and that file can be included in your `Rspec.configure` block so that it is available to all your tests.

Comment: There is relevant data there that should change test to test.. I will end up with 8-10 functions the same that with factories. Still I'm looking for a "been there, done that" kind of response.. sorry.

Comment: We use similar approach in our codebase. Unfortunately cannot share the actual code but the general idea is to pass in the "type" of campaign that you want to create and related products, orders and order_items. Various attributes we use are type of campaign, state of campaign, state of order, quantity of order items.

Comment: So you ended up with a kind of Factory Methods approach on top of factories. That can be cleaner than complex factories with tricky callbacks, it's true.

Comment: Right. Keeps the factories cleaner and also not all the specs need a "factory" that creates 6 different objects with various parameters.

Edit: Also prevents us from coupling `campaign` and `order_items` as there is no `belongs_to` relationship there.

I am curious to see if others have a better idea though.